# angular : how can i clone an object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am tyrinig to clone an object, do you know if exist a better solution of this one?

> this.objClone =
>   JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.obj));

I am using redux and i have this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'value' of object
>   '[object Object]'

Comment: if you need a deep clone.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
this.objClone = Object.assign({}, this.obj);
```

you can also use use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) :

lodash is recommended for lot of objects / array manipulations

possible copy of [Cloning objects TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907903/cloning-objects-typescript) , [What's alternative to angular.copy in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688517/whats-alternative-to-angular-copy-in-angular) or [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [spread operator](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/spread-operator.html) for that.

```
let original = {value: 'test'};
let copy = {...original};
copy.value = 'new test';

console.log(original.value)// -> 'test'
console.log(copy.value) // -> 'new test'
```

Comment: i am using redux and when i use your proposal i have this errror
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'value' of object '[object Object]'

Comment: This is a shallow cloning. If you have anything deeper than 1 level, it will be the same object.
For example, this code will print 5
var x ={
    a: {
        b: 1
    }
};
var y = {...x};
x.a.b=5;
console.log(y.a.b);

Answer (score 0):

you can use Lodash's [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) but JSON clone have better performance

Comment: Please don't refer to an entire library for something that can be done in Native Typescript.

Comment: @Nicolas Well you know these days webpack knows how to include only the imported function and not an entire library.

Comment: I know, but if OP's did not specified the use of such library, I don't see the point of suggesting it. You answer is not wrong, far from it. It just does not seams relevent to the current context.

Comment: @Nicolas Idk the use of JSON clone kind of implies that he wants to deep clone