# Js copy objects from array without reference

Tags: javascript

I hava a problem with copy a objects to array. I think it is an problem with reference.

In my program i have few array. First is dataForMonth -  it is array of objects with data for month. And second is an products array which contains products objects.  Product have property forecastArry wchich is array of objects.

Here code :

```
this.allProducts.map(function (product) {

            var dataForMonth = data.filter(function (e) {
                return e.dataId === product.productDataId;
            });

            var z = { posId: product.sales_plan_pos_id, arry: [] }
            for (var sheetMonth of sheet.channels) {
                var result = dataForMonth.filter(function (e) {
                    return e.CHANNEL === sheetMonth.CHANNEL;
                });

           product.forecastArry[someId].channels = result;
);
```

The problem is that the every changed channels property have the same value -  its a value from last product? 
Anybody know how to fix it ?

Comment: Sounds like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150967/typescript-cloning-object

Comment: why doesn't call back fucniton of map return anything??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to edit each `product` in `this.allProducts`. So you want to add a return value to your map. You should also use `let` so that the scope of variables declared is preserved within map function, although I believe the `map` function already takes care of that. In addition, not that you have to reassign this.allProducts to your map function call. So your answer should be something like the following:

```js
this.allProducts = this.allProducts.map(function (product) {

  let dataForMonth = data.filter(function (e) {
      return e.dataId === product.productDataId;
  });

  let channelsForMont = [];
  let z = { posId: product.sales_plan_pos_id, arry: [] }
  for (let sheetMonth of sheet.channels) {
      let result = dataForMonth.filter(function (e) {
          return e.CHANNEL === sheetMonth.CHANNEL;
      });

 product.forecastArry[someId].channels = channelsForMont;
 return product;
);
```

P.S Your original code has some missing brackets and `result` variable is unused. You should do something about them.

Comment: still the same :/