# Typescript Interface Assignment

Tags: typescript, interface

In my code. I have an interface like this.

```
interface MyFlag {
   flag1: boolean,
   flag2: boolean
}
```

in my code I do this.

```
let myFlag: MyFlag = {"flag1":true, "flag2": true};
let dummy = myFlag;
console.log("dummy: " + JSON.stringify(dummy));
myFlag = {"flag1": false, "flag2": false};
console.log("dummy2 : " + JSON.stringify(dummy));
```

Here are my log results:

```
dummy: {"flag1":true, "flag2": true};
dummy2 : {"flag1":false, "flag2": false};
```

What I can't understand is that how come "dummy" is changing the value when I change myFlag.

My question is "Is there a way to make 'dummy' stay as the previously assigned value. My guess is that it is because of it being a interface.

Help is appreciated.

Cheers and Regards,

SD

Comment: `dummy` is just another reference pointing to the same object as `myFlag`.  It has nothing to do with interfaces.

Comment: When you assign dummy = myFlag they are both referencing the same object.  So you have one object with two reference variables for the same object. You need to make a copy of myFlag

Comment: here is a post on cloning objects in typescript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150967/typescript-cloning-object

Answer (score 0):

> What I cant understand is that how come "dummy" is changing value when I change myFlag.

`dummy` should not be changing when you assign a new object to `myFlag`, but it should be changing when you change the internal state of `myFlag`.

Here is the code that you posted but transpiled to JavaScript. In the code, you are assigning a new object to `myFlag`, and the value of `dummy` is not changing. (That differs from the behavior you reported in your answer.)

```js
var myFlag = {
    "flag1": true,
    "flag2": true
};

var dummy = myFlag;
console.log("dummy: " + JSON.stringify(dummy));

myFlag = { "flag1": false, "flag2": false };
console.log("dummy2 : " + JSON.stringify(dummy));

// dummy: {"flag1":true,"flag2":true}
// dummy2 : {"flag1":true,"flag2":true}
```

You are probably experiencing the difference between 1. changing the state of the object to which a variable refers and 2. changing the value of the reference that a variable contains. Here is an illustrative example:

```js
let foo = {
    value: "first"
};

// at this point, foo and bar hold references to the same object
let bar = foo;

console.log(foo.value + " " + bar.value); // first first

// here, we are changing the internal state of that object
// both variables change
foo.value = "second";
console.log(foo.value + " " + bar.value); // second second

// here, we are changing the value of the reference that foo contians
// at this point, foo and bar hold references to different objects 
foo = {
    value: "third"
};

console.log(foo.value + " " + bar.value); // third second

// here, we are changing the internal state of bar's object
// which has no impact on the internal state of foo's object
bar.value = "fourth";
console.log(foo.value + " " + bar.value); // third fourth
```