# Angular2 - Clone array of typed Object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of typed object and I need to create a separated copy of it in order to be able to work on a clone.

I have to pass to configuratorProduct the copy of listProducts value:

```
  listProducts: Product[];
  configuratorProducts : Product[];
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
  this.configuratorProducts = this.listProducts.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
    for(let p in this.configuratorProducts)
    {
      var ck = this.accessories.filter(x=> x.idProductParent == p.idProduct);
    }
```

The problem is that compiler returns:

**Property 'idProduct' does not exist on
type 'string'**

How can i solve it ?

Thanks to support

Comment: what is the type of Product .?

Comment: Its a simple class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use this clone function

```
const clone = obj =>
  Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.map(item => clone(item))
    : obj instanceof Date
      ? new Date(obj.getTime())
      : (typeof obj === 'object') && obj
        ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((o, prop) => ({ ...o, [prop]: clone(obj[prop]) }), {})
        : obj;
```

See a demo here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qmzgf7

If it is an array it returns an array of each item cloned, if it is a date it creates a new date, if it is an object if reduces the properties onto a new object with each property cloned. If none of these it is a value object or a function and just return it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy using the spread operator

`this.configuratorProducts = [...this.listProducts]`

Answer (score 1):

`Property 'idProduct' does not exist on type 'string'` because there `p` is `string`, you made a simple mistake

```
for(let p in this.configuratorProducts)
{
  ...
}
```

should be

```
for(let p of this.configuratorProducts)
    {
      ...
    }
```

`for(let p in this.configuratorProducts)` is use to iterate keys of object, which are string. `of` is used to iterate values, which here are `Product`

And there are two type of cloning: Deep Clone and Shallow Clone, research well before using any.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use general static clone tool?

For example:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ObjectCloneUtility{

  public static clone(obj: Object): Object {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    let copy = obj.constructor();
    for (let attr in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        copy[attr] = obj[attr];
      }
    }
    return copy;
  }
}
```

(I found this in SO, but honestly couldn't find the original answer.)

Or, maybe other [clone solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150967/typescript-cloning-object) could work for you as well.