# Should I declare a variable or access object method?

Tags: angular, typescript

Which is the better practice and why?

Declare a variable:

```
exampleFunction(requestData: Object) {
  const username = requestData.username;

  doSomething(username);
}
```

Or access the object property directly?

```
exampleFunction(requestData: Object) {
  doSomething(requestData.username);
}
```

What if the code I use is over 50 lines long and the variable is used multiple times. Should I use the variable 'username' multiple times or use 'requestData.username' multiple times?

Comment: If you are asking for an opinion: It depends, and it is a preference.

Comment: I'm wondering which one of these options is the better practice.

Comment: In above context, access object property is better, I think. There is no need to declare a variable to hold it. And if you are using a better IDE like, it will suggest to use second, in the above context.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a best practice, but for sure `requestData` is too broad. What does requestData contains ?

Comment: I would go for the second option. Its much cleaner this way.

Comment: As per my point of view, in the first case, you need an extra variable which is not actually required as you don't process it further in the same block. So, I recommend the second one in your scenario.

Comment: What if the actual code is over 60 lines long and the variable is used multiple times in different places?

Comment: then the first case is recommended so that you'll find it easy to process it with less/safe typing

Comment: Depends on how costly it is to access the property (which is usually more costly than a variable access indeed, but with the optimisations in modern compilers, not by much).

Comment: I see my question has been put on hold for being primarily opinion-based. If this is the case I guess I can conclude there is no better practice between the two.

Answer (score 5):

V8 Javascript Engine performs some optimization pre-processing the code and checking if some variable can be deleted or if there's some regular pattern in the code, in order to reduce the execution payload.

For this reason, there are no memory issues in using a form or another, at least using V8 engine (for example, Chrome or NodeJS).

Even if this optimization isn't performed, it's just a pointer or a primitive variable, so it won't cost more than few bytes.

It's different if we talk about the cost of transmitting code. We know that JavaScript isn't a compiled language and it needs to reach the client's computer to be executed, so every space, indentation, semicolon, will cost in order of time used to transfer.

To reduce this cost, you can uglify and minify your code, but usually this type of optimization isn't performed.

Finally, it's impossible to think a scenario where it can make a difference, so I advise you to use the form that you think it's more readable and no matter of other parameters.

Comment: Nicely explained!

Comment: I think my answer needs some source, I'm going to add something later

Answer (score 5):

By refactoring of Martin Fowler is a technique ([Replace Temp with Query](https://refactoring.guru/replace-temp-with-query)).

after that you will go to second variant

```
cloneFullProject(requestData: Object) {
  doSomething(requestData.username);
}
```

But it is smell too ([Middle Man](https://refactoring.guru/smells/middle-man)).

As a conclusion in *this example*, it is better to remove this method altogether :)

However, there are cases when is preferable first example. For instance:
 you have several methods that take `requestData.username` parameters.

```
exampleFunction(requestData: Object) {
  const username = requestData.username;

  doSomething1(username);
  doSomething2(username);
  ...
}
```

And in this case temporary variable is justified

Answer (score 3):

First option pros:

1. Readable code
2. You can debug and validate value before passing to another method

First option cons:

1. It will create unnecessary variables and consume more memory

Comment: You should never use `let` instead of `const`.

Comment: My bad let me update answer

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are `referencing` an object, not cloning it.
The right way of cloning is throug Object.assign() or lodash (or similar) _.cloneDeep(), or spread operator or whatever.

Please refer to [typescript - cloning object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150967/typescript-cloning-object/42758108) for more info about cloning.

Coming to the question, when you have a single variable to work both has the same readability in a such short method.

Just because the method is so short I would prefer the latter one, as reading a single line of code explain what property of the object I'm passing to my method instead of reverse-reading the code.

For my own taste and general opinion destructuring is the cleanest way another programmer would expect from your code:

```
const { username, var1, var2 }  = requestData;
```

Comment: What if he does not need to clone it and need a reference instead of deep copying the object?

Comment: This is a small example. The actual code I'm working with is about 60 lines of code where the variable is used more than once.

Comment: I pointed out this only because the code mock is not clear about it and cloneFullProject is pretty semantic but can be misleading

Comment: If variable are used more than once you can use destructuring, which is even more clear: `const {username, var2, var3, var4} = requestData;'

Comment: The function name is not relevant right now, I'm not sure if you understood the question.

Comment: Yes I've understood, I'll report my destructuring comment in the answer

Answer (score 1):

> Primarily, it is an opinion based question. So, the answer given below is my point of view.

- In the first case, you need an extra variable which is **not actually required** as you don't process it further in the same block. So, I recommend the **second one** with *direct property access* in your scenario & is **more readable** too.
- If you have a scenario where your actual code is over 60 lines long (or so) and the variable is used multiple times in different places, you can use the **first case** with *an extra variable*,  so that you'll find it **easy to process it with less/ safe typing**.