# Object copying issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I copied obj1 to obj2  but when I make changes in obj2 the object  obj1 value is also changing. How to stop this?

```
  let p24:   ProductModule=new ProductModule();
                              p24=  this.productlist[g];
                              p24.variants=[];
                              p24.variants.push(p.variants[h]);
                                  this.newproductlist.push(p24);
```

here  `this.productlist[g]` is an array but when i perform  `p24.variants=[];`
acction value inside `this.productlist[g]` also became empty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150967/typescript-cloning-object

Comment: `p24 = this.productlist[g];`**does not** create a copy, the `new ProductModule();` of the previous line isn't being used at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to clone object in Javascript.

Simplest way (Deep clone/copy);

```
p24=  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.productlist[g]));
```

Note : By doing this, you may loose the original type of Object.

Or you can also look at [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) , [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and spread(...object) operator as suggested by JGFMK

Comment: Or use spread operator if shallow copy sufficient. `let copy = { ...original };`

Answer (score 1):

When you assign javascript oject to another object, both will point to same memory location. that's the reason if you update on one obejct, the same will be updated another. To avoid this

**Option 1 :**

```
p24 =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.productlist[g]));
```

**Option 2 :**

```
p24 =   {...this.productlist[g]};
```

Comment: Property 'slice' does not exist on type 'ProductModule'.ts(2339)

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are value types and objects are reference types:

[image]

So assigning an object variable to another object variable causes them both to reference (point to) the same object.

You need to *copy* the instance instead using one of the techniques shown in the other answers.

[NOTE: This syntax shown uses C# instead of TypeScript, but conceptually it works the same.]