# Typescript Cloning object not working well

Tags: typescript, clone

I'm trying to create an typescript from another one.
The problem is when I change the property og the cloned object, it changes the property of the source object as well.

Example :

```
import { arrayProp, ModelType, prop, staticMethod, Typegoose, instanceMethod, InstanceType } from 'typegoose';
class User extends Typegoose
{
    @prop({ required: true })
    name: string;
    @prop({ required: true })
    password: string;
    ...
    @instanceMethod
    renderSafe(this: InstanceType<User>)
    {
        let _return:any = null;

        try
        {
            _return = <any>Object.create(this);
            _return.password = undefined;

            console.log(_return);
            // prints correct object without password property

            console.log(this.password);
            // prints undefined
        }
        catch(e)
        { console.log(e); }

        return _return;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to clone object so the result could live without affect the source object ?
I've also tried using `Object.assign({}, this);` it leads to the same problem.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150967/typescript-cloning-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript - cloning object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150967/typescript-cloning-object)

Comment: The related post doesn't provide a working solution.

Comment: Your password was undefined already, so you didn't change it on the clone.

Comment: @ritaj no it's not undefined. `[..]` means I skipped a part of the code which contains the constructor. In the constructor `password` is defined and assigned.

Comment: Well then the problem is somewhere else. `let user = {password: 'pass'}; let clone = Object.create(user); clone.password = "changed"; console.log(user.password); ` prints "pass".

Comment: @ritaj when I do it inside the class using `Object.create(this);` it's not working. You could try it.

Comment: I just tried it and it works.

Comment: Solved the problem by using disguting code _return = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));

Comment: Maybe you don't have the same result cause I didn't tell that the class is extending Typegoose.