# Clone array of object removes class type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types, deep-copy

I have to deep clone an array of objects

```
  filterList: Filter[] = [
    new ChipsFilter('Rating', 'rating',
      [
        {
          name: '5 ★',
          key: '5',
          value: true
        },
        {
          name: '4 ★',
          key: '4',
          value: true
        },
        {
          name: '3 ★',
          key: '3',
          value: true
        },
        {
          name: '2 ★',
          key: '2',
          value: true
        },
        {
          name: '1 ★',
          key: '1',
          value: true
        }
      ]),
    new CheckboxFilter('Country', 'country', [
      {
        name: 'India',
        key: 'india',
        value: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Brazil',
        key: 'brazil',
        value: false
      },
      {
        name: 'UAE',
        key: 'uae',
        value: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Sri Lanka',
        key: 'sri-lanka',
        value: true
      },
      {
        name: 'USA',
        key: 'usa',
        value: false
      },
      {
        name: 'England',
        key: 'england',
        value: true
      },
      {
        name: 'South Africa',
        key: 'south-africa',
        value: true
      }
    ]),
    new CalendarFilter('Date', 'createdAt', [
      {
        name: 'Start Date',
        key: 'startDate',
        value: ''
      },
      {
        name: 'End Date',
        key: 'endDate',
        value: ''
      }
    ]),
  ];
```

After clone I want the data type of objects to be same but I get the object as the type instead, have tried below methods for cloning.

1. Using JSON stringify

```
this.filterList = this.filterList.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
```

2. Using object.assign

```
this.filterList = this.filterList.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
```

Comment: `Object.assign` used that way is not going to clone objects in a way that preserves type information. Depending on the structure of those classes (which you don't show) it may not clone them at all.

Comment: Using Object.assign(...) says assign the second argument to the structure represented in the first argument - in this case, it is an Object object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript - cloning object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150967/typescript-cloning-object)

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `Object.assign()` is the target object. That object effectively is the result. What `Object.assign()` does is just copy over own enumerable properties of your `CalendarFilter` instances to that target.

What you could do instead is create new instances of your objects in `array.map()` instead of assigning them to a generic object with `Object.assign()`.

```
this.filterList = this.filterList.map(a => new CalendarFilter(...))
```

Of course, you need to use the right constructor for each type you encounter in your array.

Comment: there not just CalendarFilter, have a look at the example it shows 3 types of class objects

Answer (score 0):

This will take into account the variable Object types:

```js
class ChipsFilter {constructor(){this.chipsProp="chipsProp"}}
class CheckboxFilter {constructor(){this.checkboxProp= "checkboxProp"}}
class CalendarFilter {constructor(){this.calendarProp= "calendarProp"}}

const filterList = [
  new ChipsFilter(),
  new CheckboxFilter(),
  new CalendarFilter(),
];

let out = filterList.map(obj=>Object.assign(new obj.constructor, obj));
console.log(out[0].constructor, out[0]);
console.log(out[1].constructor, out[1]);
console.log(out[2].constructor, out[2]);
```

Comment: Getting error: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.ts(2351)

Comment: That's a typescript linting problem. You can clearly see this works.